# Passing Kerberos Credentials from Web Service to WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

A system I'm working on has a web service which calls a WCF service. The request to the web service is received with the user's Kerberos credentials and we want to call the WCF service using these credentials.

Is it possible? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. You may have to use the WCF delegation. Delegation is perfect fit for backend service calls with the authentication done on front end.

Please refer to [Delegates and Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088.aspx). The impersonation level set to Delegate would enable you to authenticate a service running in a different machine from the caller server.